# How to make Tool bar Icon actionable in android?

Tags: android

I have a Tool bar in main activity in which I have a refresh icon which is actionable right now But problem is that when I click refresh icon it opens a popup menu like this

[image: ActionBar]

when I again click on this text it refresh page .what I want to refresh page without this text only when I click refresh icon it will refresh page  not to show this "refresh" text.

here is my code for menu :-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Refresh"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"/>
```

and here is my main activity code:-

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.refresh) {
        refreshContent();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void refreshContent() {
    m_oPDialog = new ProgressDialog(CMainActivity.this);progressbar onclick refresh button
    m_oPDialog.setMessage("Refreshing...");
    m_oPDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    m_oPDialog.setCancelable(false);
    m_oPDialog.show();

    long delayInMillis = 3000;
    m_oTimer = new Timer();
    m_oTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_oPDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, delayInMillis);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of your question, you want to hide the title i.e. Refresh...just make the title field blank i.e.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh_icon"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"/>
```

Comment: @RaghvenderKumar just make android:showAsAction="never"